# Printing out all timezones in C

Tags: c, time, timezone

I'm looking to print out the current time in a specified timezone in c. I understand that the time.h library has a few ways of displaying time but I can't figure out how to change those times depending on an inputted timezone. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`tzset()` function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tzset). Note that this sets the time zone globally for your whole process, since it reads from the `TZ` environment variable (which is also process-global).

To change the `TZ` environment variable, you can use [`putenv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putenv) which takes a formatted environment variable in the form `TZ=Europe/Paris` for example.

Comment: tzset(), in order to change, from tz1 to tz2 to tz3, the way the OP mentioned, requires setting the TZ variable first, then calling tzset().  You might want to elaborate on putenv() as well.  @Greg Hewgill

Comment: @jimmcnamara: Thanks, added more info.

Comment: Be cautious with `putenv()`; you leak memory if you're not careful.  Generally, using [`setenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setenv.html) is a better choice than `putenv()`, though `putenv()` certainly works as long as you are careful about the string(s) you supply to it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That's true. Not all platforms support `setenv()`, though.

Comment: True: `setenv()` was added in [POSIX 2004](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/), not present in the previous version (1997, at least for the [SUS](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/), Single Unix Specification).  So, some non-Linux systems may not have caught up yet (but Mac OS X, and probably all the BSD variants, are OK).